# How to improve UI Selection logic?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, logic

So I have this piece of code to **select objects in the UI on hover**, and to store the currently hovered element in the class scope with **`hoveredAction`**.

I feel like there would be a **more elegant approach** of this logic. I know that I could add one more check to avoid some computation if the raycasted object is the same as the stored one, but the "boilerplate" `else if (hoveredAction != null)` would persist.

This isn't the first time I come across this kind of logic, but this time it is simple enough for me to summarize it, any Idea would help.

```
    void Update()
    {
        pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(eventSystem)
        {
            position = Input.mousePosition
        };
        List<RaycastResult> results = new();
        raycaster.Raycast(pointerEventData, results);
        if (results.Count > 0)
        {
            var result = results[0];
            var obj = allowedActions.Where(a => result.gameObject == a.UiObject.gameObject);
            if (obj.Count() > 0)
            {
                hoveredAction = obj.First();
                hoveredAction.UiObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = shown;
            }
            else if(hoveredAction != null)
            {
                hoveredAction.UiObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = hidden;
                hoveredAction = null;
            }
        }
        else if (hoveredAction != null) 
        {
            hoveredAction.UiObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = hidden;
            hoveredAction = null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that yours this is also not complete: In the case `if (obj.Count() > 0)` you also will want to set any previous hit to `hidden` ... or skip both if `previous hit == current`

I would split it up and only track the newCurrent hit an do e.g.

```
void Update()
{
    pointerEventData = new PointerEventData(eventSystem)
    {
        position = Input.mousePosition
    };

    List<RaycastResult> results = new();

    raycaster.Raycast(pointerEventData, results);

    // whenever you deal with linq make sure to iterate only once!
    Gamebject currentHoveredAction = results.Count == 0 ? null : allowedActions.Where(a => result.gameObject == a.UiObject.gameObject).FirstOrDefault();

    // This is 
    // - either you hit a different object than before
    // - you didn't hit anything before but do now
    // - or you did hit something before but nothing now
    if(hoveredAction != currentHoveredAction)
    {
        // if there is a previous hit reset it
        if (hoveredAction != null) 
        {
            hoveredAction.UiObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = hidden;
        }

        // if there is a current hit set it
        if(currentHoveredAction != null)
        {
            currentHoveredAction.UiObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = show; 
        }

        // either way store the new result
        hoveredAction = currentHoveredAction;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I asked for, works perfectly. Thanks for the Linq heads-up too.